# Evaluate an int, char and int

Tags: c++, char, int, addition, subtraction

My issue is that my current application I am working on needs to add an int to another int with a char.

The code can explain it better.

```
const char operatorArray[3] = {'+', '-', 'x'}; 
int randOperator = rand() % 3;
char Operator = operatorArray[randOperator];

int a = 1;
int b = 2;
```

So here I have an operator (Operator) that is a char, and two numbers that are integers.

I sort of want (a operator b) so like 1+2 for example and too put that answer in a variable.

Comment: what about `if (Operator == '+') {return a+b;}` ?

Answer (score 0):

Using a `switch` statement seems appropriate:

```
int c;

switch(Operator)
{
case '+':
    c = a + b;
    break;
case '-':
    c = a - b;
    break;
case 'x':
    c = a * b;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define somewhere bits of code defining what your operators do. Fortunately, C++11 helps you with that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
T eval(char op, T a, T b)
{
    static const std::map<char, std::function<T(T, T)> > operators = {
        { '+', [](T a, T b){return a + b; } },
        { '-', [](T a, T b){return a - b; } },
        { '/', [](T a, T b){return a / b; } },
    };
    auto it = operators.find(op);
    return it->second(a, b);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "3       +  4    = " << eval('+', 3, 4) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "3.0     -  1.5  = " << eval('-', 3.0, 1.5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "(-2.f)  /  8.f = "  << eval('/', -2.f, 8.f) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile with `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror main.cpp`.

Output:

```
3       +  4    = 7
3.0     -  1.5  = 1.5
(-2.f)  /  8.f  = -0.25
```